# Как определить сторону столкновения с коллайдером?

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет! Делаю бесконечный "раннер", где игрок стоит на месте, а карта уже двигается на игрока, игрок может лишь двигаться влево и вправо. Хочу избегая триггеров заставить определять сторону столкновения с коллайдером. Например при попытке сдвинуться в сторону, то отскочить назад и, допустим, потерять здоровье, а если лобовое столкновение, то GameOver.

Пытался сделать через рейкаст, но он срабатывает как-то через раз, то есть то возвращает правильно, то возвращает **Direction.None**

```
public static class UnityGameUtils
{
    public static Direction GetColliderHitDirection(GameObject gameObject, GameObject hitGameObject)
    {
        RaycastHit raycastHit;
        Vector3 direction = (gameObject.transform.position - hitGameObject.transform.position).normalized;
        Ray ray = new Ray(gameObject.transform.position, direction);
        Debug.DrawRay(gameObject.transform.position, direction);
        
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out raycastHit))
        {
            if(raycastHit.collider != null)
            {
                Vector3 raycastNormal = raycastHit.normal;
                raycastNormal = raycastHit.transform.TransformDirection(raycastNormal);
                
                if(raycastNormal == raycastHit.transform.up)
                {
                    return Direction.Top;
                }
                if (raycastNormal == -raycastHit.transform.up)
                {
                    return Direction.Bottom;
                }
                if (raycastNormal == raycastHit.transform.forward)
                {
                    return Direction.Forward;
                }
                if (raycastNormal == -raycastHit.transform.forward)
                {
                    return Direction.Back;
                }
                if (raycastNormal == raycastHit.transform.right)
                {
                    return Direction.Right;
                }
                if (raycastNormal == -raycastHit.transform.right)
                {
                    return Direction.Left;
                }
            }
        }

        return Direction.None;
    }
}
```

**PlayerMovementController:**

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Barrier")
    {
        Direction hitDirection = UnityGameUtils.GetColliderHitDirection(this.gameObject, collision.gameObject);
        if (hitDirection == Direction.Forward)
        {
            this.CanMove = false;
            PlayerMovement.OnBarrierHit?.Invoke(this);
        }
    }
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "HighGround" || collision.gameObject.tag == "Barrier")
    {
        Direction hitDirection = UnityGameUtils.GetColliderHitDirection(this.gameObject, collision.gameObject);
        if (hitDirection == Direction.Right || hitDirection == Direction.Left)
        {
            this.pointFinish = this.pointStart;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если я всё правильно понял, то вам стоит копать в эту сторону
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.ClosestPoint.html

Answer (score 0):

Допустим ось x - это ось перемещения влево/вправо. Мы узнаём размеры нашего объекта по оси x и делим на 2 и делаем чуть меньше(необязательно). Теперь узнаём координаты нашего игрока с помощью `transfowm.position.x` и делаем две переменные: начало игрока и коней игрока по оси x , от первой отнимает ко второй прибавляем, ну теперь просто при столкновении сравниваем координаты объекта с которым столкнулись и эти две переменные. Как то так

```
public PlayerSizeX;

if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Barrier")
{
 private float PSX = transform.position.x - PlPlayerSizeX/2 + 1f; //можно изменять 1f 
 private float PFX = transform.position.x + PlPlayerSizeX/2 - 1f; //можно изменять 1f 
    Direction hitDirection = UnityGameUtils.GetColliderHitDirection(this.gameObject, collision.gameObject);
    if (transform.position.x > PSX && PFX > transform.position.x)
    {
        this.CanMove = false;
        PlayerMovement.OnBarrierHit?.Invoke(this);
    }
 else
 {
  if(collision.gameObject.transform.position.x > transform.position.x)
  {
    // Толкаемся влево     можно через addForce()
  }
  else
  {
    // Толкаемся вправо    можно через addForce()
  }
 }
}
```

Я думаю это будет работать, **Но это подойдет только, если ваш персонаж не вращается(направлен перпендикулярно оси x) и объекты двигаются к нему спереди или сзади**

Comment: Будет проблема, т.к. при попадании на рампу, на которую он должен заезжать, при сравнении координат по оси X будет тоже отталкиваться в сторону